# Create Custom Page in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working on [PayPal Button Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-wp-button-manager/) Plugin of wordpress.

Here we are doing some extension in the plugin.
For that we want to add some **Custom links** and **Custom Page**.

At First We are Listing Paypal Buttons with the Action Links

- Edit
- Quick Edit
- View
- Trash

[image]

Now I am stuck at the point of the Create custom page,
I have added **"Update Button"** Link with **post_row_actions** Successfully but Cant create new page with that link.

Any Logic/ good way how can I do that ?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add View button instead off update button as wordpress has it's deafult edit So you have to follow below steps to achive this:

**Step1:** Add function for add **view** link:

```
function viewbutton_row_actions( $actions, WP_Post $post ) {
        if ( $post->post_type != 'paypal_buttons' ) {
            return $actions;
        }

        $actions['view-custombutton'] = '<a href="'.admin_url().'post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=edit&myname=bhumi">View</a>';
        return $actions;
    }
    add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'viewbutton_row_actions', 10, 2 );
```

**Step2:**

In paypal button manager there has condition in **paypal-wp-button-manager\admin\partials\class-paypal-wp-button-manager-post-types** on line around 288 in paypal_wp_button_manager_metabox function if you have any created shortcode then it displays shortcodes readonly view on edit link but now you have to add new condition like this if (isset($paypal_button_html) && !empty($paypal_button_html) && $_GET['myname']=="bhumi") so now its displays shortcodes readonly onclick of view link otherwise it shows edit post page.

Comment: Thank you SO much WordPress Hero